# My c++ program terminated without taking the input.What should i do?

Tags: c++

The code below,works fine but it does not take any value for age and terminates.`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class user{
    int id,level=1,kills=0,age;
    char name[20],server[40];
public:

void get(){
    cout<<"Enter your name:";
    cin>>name[20];
    cout<<"Enter your age:";
    cin>>age;

}
};
int main(){
    user u;
    u.get();
    return 0;
}
/*Output
Enter your name:Jack
Enter your age:
C:\Users\user\documents\c++
*/
```

In the output section ,age is not accepted and the program terminates.

Comment: What if, instead of char Name[] you use std::string? Also you should use cin >> name.

Comment: `cin>>name[20];` accesses `name` out of range, and then tries to read a single character into an invalid array element. Use `cin >> name;` instead, or even better `std::string`.

Comment: You could replace ```name[20];``` with just ```name;``` in the ```cin``` statement but that could also be a problem since the ```cin``` statement doesn't consider spaces. So if you input two words it will neglect the space. You could add the header file ```'studio.h'``` and replace ```cin>>name[20];``` with ```gets(name);```, that would consider spaces if you are inputting a full name.

Comment: @Sujit `gets` is from `stdio.h`, and was remove in C++14 anyway. If anything, OP should use `cin.getline()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry I made a typo... Oh I didn't know it was removed

Answer (score 2):

Use `string name` instead of `char name[20]` to take multi-character value. char name[20] will terminate after taking a single character.

Also, its valued will not be displayed on giving output.

Modified code for reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class user{
    int id,level=1,kills=0,age;
    string name,server;
public:

void get(){
    cout<<"Enter your name:";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter your age:";
    cin>>age;
}

//test output
void put(){
    cout<<name<<endl;
    cout<<age<<endl;
}
};
int main(){
    user u;
    u.get();
    //test
    u.put();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the code to this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class user{
    int id,level=1,kills=0,age;
    char name[20],server[40];
public:

void get(){
    cout<<"Enter your name:";
    cin>>name; // changes done here
    cout<<"Enter your age:";
    cin>>age;

}
};
int main(){
    user u;
    u.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Job Done :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Anish,it helped.Could you also explain why it didn't work before?

Comment: Yup !! Bro. In char array, if you want to take input once only, then you only have to provide the name of the array only. In C programming, the collection of characters is stored in the form of arrays, this is also supported in C++ programming. Hence it's called C-strings.
C-strings are arrays of type char terminated with null character, that is, \0 (ASCII value of null character is 0).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
    cin>>name[20];
```

Why:

'name[20]' is 21th char of the array you defined before. It counts from 0! As this, it is simply a single char. If you now enter more than a single char, the rest is read by the `cin>>age`.

Example:

```
    cout<<"Enter your name:";
    cin>>name[20];
    cout<<"Enter your age:";
    cin>>age;

    std::cout << "Name " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Age " << age << std::endl;
```

And entering:

```
Enter your name:1234
Enter your age:Name 
Age 234
```

As you see, the '1' is now in the name and the rest is stored in age.

But attention: You defined your array as `name[20], which means you have 0..19 elements. Accessing name[20] is wrong!

But what you simply want to do was:

```
cin >> name;
```

Comment: @Kevin: If you find an answer on SO nice, give an upvote! If the answer solves your problem, accept it please. You can do both :-)

Comment: "'name[20]' is 20th char of the array" - No. It's the 21st char of the array. Array indices start at 0. That char is out of bounds.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: yepp, fixed

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle strings (a long sequence of characters) or even the strings that have spaces just use the following library in C++.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

Then just declare a string variable.

```
String name;
```

Now you can save a very long string without any error. e.g.

```
name = jshkad skshdur kslsjue djsdf2341;
```

and you'll get no error, enjoy ;)